# bootstrap with f.select not setting width properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, form-for

I have a select field in a table and I can't seem to set the width properly. Initially, I tried just using a span but that didn't work. Then, if I try using %select the options for select sit outside of the actual select dropdown. here's my code right now:

```
  %td= line_item.link_to_remove raw('<i class="icon-remove"></i>'), :class => "btn btn-mini"
  %td= line_item.select :type, @types
  %td= line_item.text_field :description, :rows => 2, :style => "width:85%;"
  %td= line_item.text_field :quantity, :class => "input-mini quantity"
  %td= line_item.text_field :rate, :class => "input-mini rate"
```

I've also tried this:

```
  %td= line_item.link_to_remove raw('<i class="icon-remove"></i>'), :class => "btn btn-mini"
  %td
    %select= line_item.select :type, @types
  %td= line_item.text_field :description, :rows => 2, :style => "width:85%;"
  %td= line_item.text_field :quantity, :class => "input-mini quantity"
  %td= line_item.text_field :rate, :class => "input-mini rate"
```

this sets the width properly but the options for select don't appear (they are outside )

what am i doing wrong? thanks!

EDIT: what it says I need to do in bootstrap is use the select input type and then use span2 to make it smaller...but it doesn't seem to be working or I'm not sure how to implement that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`%td= line_item.select :type, @types, :class => 'span2'`

Comment: it's actually this: %td= line_item.select :type, @types, {}, :class => 'span2'
it required the {} because otherwise it didn't read the class